# socket.io / node.js with ssl and Access-Control-Header

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, access-control

I set up a node-server and get an error message when activating ssl (official, NOT self-assigned Certificate).

The error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://servername:8081/socket.io/... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://servername' is therefore not allowed access. results:1
```

But actually, I included the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
</IfModule>
```

The apache header module is installed.

my server:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var express = require ('express');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('path to key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('path to cert'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('path to ca')
};

app = express()
https.createServer(options,app).listen(8081)
var io = require('socket.io')(https);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
...
}
```

my client:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var socket = io.connect('https://servername:8081');
    socket.emit(...);
</script>
```

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see a few things here:

- You need to include the socket.io lib **in your client** like so:

  ```html
  <script src="https://servername:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  ```
- Set secure parameter to true (**in your client**)

  ```js
  var socket = io.connect('https ://servername:8081', {secure: true});
  ```
- And add these lines to your SSL options :

  ```js
  agent: false, 
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false
  ```
- Then if it still doesn't work you can try setting up your **server** using :

  ```js
  io.set('match origin protocol', true);
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's getting better, but now I get the error   "[blocked] The page at 'https://servername' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'ws://servername/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=HXfZn3PhvDcimhztAAAC': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 socket.io.js:4519
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: AND: When starting the node-server it says: "Option match origin protocol is not valid. Please refer to the README."